# Select option doesn't stay after you return from another URL

Tags: php, wordpress, post, select

I have the following php code :

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    global $user_ID;
    $user_lang = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
    $selected_locale = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
    $selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'];
    echo 'UserLang: '. $user_lang.'<br/>';
    echo 'Selected Locale: '. $selected_locale.'<br/>';
?>
    <div class="field" style="margin-top:-10px;">
        <div style="padding:10px;">
            <form name="setLanguage" id="setLanguage"  method="POST">
                <select name="LanguageOption" onchange="change()">
                    <option value="" <?php if(false !== stripos($selected_locale, ' ')) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Default ( English )</option>
                    <option value="en_GB" <?php if(false !== stripos($selected_locale, 'en_GB')) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>English ( US )</option>
                    <option value="el_GR" <?php if(false !== stripos($selected_locale, 'el_GR')) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Greek</option>
                </select>
            </form>
    <script>
        function change(){
            document.getElementById("setLanguage").submit();
        }
    </script>
<?php
    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'locale', $selected_locale);
    $user_lang = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
    $selected_locale = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
    echo 'UserLang: '. $user_lang.'<br/>';
    echo 'Selected Locale: '. $selected_locale.'<br/>';
?>

<?php
    echo 'UserLang: '. $user_lang.'<br/>';
    echo 'Selected Locale: '. $selected_locale.'<br/>';

    if ($user_lang == '') { echo 'Default communication language ENGLISH';
    } elseif ($user_lang == 'en_GB') { echo 'Your communication language: ENGLISH (US)';
    }
    elseif ($user_lang == 'el_GR') { echo 'Your communication language: GREEK';
    } else {echo 'Nothing Selected';}
?>

<?php /*************************************/ ?>
```

Everything works fine even if I reload the page and the locale variable into usermeta table changes appropriately.
The problem is that if I go to some other URL of the site and I get back on this page the option goes to the first option "Default (English)" and also changes the locale field for the user too.

Is there any way I can avoid that? Could you post the modified code?

Thank you in advance
George

Comment: you are overriding with the value of $selected_locale with $_POST['LanguageOption'] every time

Comment: I need that to display the selected value after the page refreshes when someone makes a selection. How can I have a 3rd variable that "remembers" the choice and display the selected option even after the user goes and comes back from to a different page.... Or something like that. Why does it work on page reload?

Comment: as @MHewison said you are overriding the value of `$selected_locale` with `$selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'];` on row 6, if you will not call this page using `post` request then you `$selected_locale ` value will be blank and resulting the condition true for default lang English at end of your script.

Comment: if you are using php > 7 just try replacing lines 5 and 6 with ```php $selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'] ?? get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);```

Comment: I thank you all for your replies! What I want to do is after someone selects the language from the select options to update the locale field at the db, show the visitor's selection in the dropdown and display the message for the language at the bottom. If I remove the $selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption']; the selection dropdown displays the the default selection which is the Default (English) no matter what the user selects.

Comment: Yes I am using PHP 7.3.16 and I replaced :
// $user_lang = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
// $selected_locale = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
 $selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'] ?? get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true); as MHewison suggested but the problem remains....

Comment: Any other idea??

Comment: My apologies to MHewison I commented out the wrong lines. I am very sorry about that. 
after I replaced lines: 
$selected_locale = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
$selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'];
with
$selected_locale = $_POST['LanguageOption'] ?? get_user_meta($user_ID, 'locale', true);
Everything worked as a charm! ! !
I thank you very much MHewison